# Parse error while installing PhoneGap android App

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am getting an error **"Parse error - There was a problem while parsing the package"** while installing (unsigned or signed) phonegap apk. Below is the config file. I have googled for the issue. But, failed to get proper solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="ITInterviewPrepApp.lucidapps" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <name>ITInterviewPrepApp</name>
    <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
</widget>
```

Thanks,
Shree

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue as below:

1. Connected my device in debug mode (enable usb debugging under **settings->developer options**) to my PC.
2. Ran the command **adb install "Path to signed apk"** from %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools folder.

I got an error - **INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED** in command prompt.

**Issue :** In my android manifest file, the package name had uppercase characters. I assume for cordova/phonegap apps the package name should not have uppercase characters.

**Solution :** I created a new apk with package name without uppercase characters. Build, signed and I was able to install apk successfully

Note : 
**You should have android sdk installed in your machine. Your apk must be signed.**